# Memory leak with addeventlistener()

Tags: javascript

I have a modal box which opens on a button click, when the modal is visible, if the area outside the content box is clicked, then the modal should disappear.

The issue i'm having is that my modal keeps creating the modal and not being completely removed, thus creating a memory leak.

The class `show-login-modal` handles the visibility of the modal.

```
let x = 1;

function LoginPopup(){

    let modal = document.getElementById('modal');

    modal.classList.add('show-login-modal');

    let xx = x++;

    function _removeModal() {
        modal.classList.remove('show-login-modal');
        modal.removeEventListener("click", this);
    }

    modal.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        console.log(xx);
        if (event.target === modal) {
            _removeModal();
         } 
     });
}
```

I included the console.log for reference.

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Nothing in this code creates or removes the modal element.

Comment: @Amy I think it's safe to assume that the class `show-login-modal` is handling the hiding/showing of the modal.

Answer (score 2):

`removeEventListener` is being used incorrectly, it needs to be invoked with a named function. So, in your case, you'd want to move the event target detection inside of `_removeModal`

```
function _removeModal(event){ if (event.target === this){ ... modal.removeEventListener('click', _removeModal)} }

modal.addEventListener('click', _removeModal)
```

Comment: You are the real MVP. Thanks a bunch!